# How to prevent a `ViewportTexture` from extending beyond the dimensions of an imported mesh

Tags: viewport, godot-4

I have a GLTF imprted from blender that contains a few simple meshes.

It is a screen with a bezel and some buttons. The display area of the screen is a plane that extends up to the bezel:

[image]

In this image, you can see the outline of the "display" area. You can also see that the `label` that says hello extends *beyond* the bounds of the "display" plane.

I tried creating a `MeshInstance3D` and setting it's material to the same `ViewportTexture` and it works fine.

It looks to me like the `ViewportTexture` is being stretched to the dimensions of the *whole* imported scene. That is, if the exterior of the bevel is 500mm and the display area is only 450mm, it seems that the texture is projected onto a surface of 500mm wide.

I am trying to achieve the following:
[image]

For this last image, I had to use a margin container and guess the margins approximately to set the text entirely within the display area.

I feel this is a bug as the material is not applied to the `MeshInstance3D` correctly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks to me like an issue with the UVs on the mesh.